# Capacitor voltage of Buck converter with LC input filter

Tags: power-electronics, buck, low-pass, passive-filter

[image]

What will be the voltages across capacitor C1 and inductor L1 in terms of Vg,D,R? From the amp charge balance equation, i1=-io *D because i2=io.From my observation, Vc1= Vg for 0<T<DTs and Vc1= Vg-vL1 for DTs<T<Ts. But I can't reach the equation of VL1 and Vc1 using Vg,D,R. Please help me to express the equations.

Comment: Use a simulator is my advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Buck converter using LC input filter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/530294/buck-converter-using-lc-input-filter)

Comment: Actually I am a newbie in power electronics... The material you provided was too difficult for me to understand. I got the answer Vout=DVg and I1=-DIout but facing difficulty in input filter  observation